# vba - copy first row from another sheet, and put it as a dropdown menu in current

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make something like that:

in one file I have a table, with many columns, and the first cell of each column is the title.
now, I want to grab those column's titles, and put them in another file as a dropdown menu, which the user can select (so he can select which column he would like to see).

any ideas on how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply use data validation for a cell while setting the range of the headers as list? What kind of dropdown are you going to use? Just a cell? Or an active x element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I did something, isn't most elegant but works fine, with a bit of tweeking:

```
    Set s_wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    For i = 1 To 4
        strData = strData & "," & s_wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
    s_wbk.Close

    formattedData = Split(strData, ",")
    firstCell = "E1"
    lastCell = "E" & (UBound(formattedData) - 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(formattedData)
        Cells(i, 5).Value = formattedData(i)
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 3")).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = firstCell & ":" & lastCell
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .DropDownLines = 8
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
    Range("D8").Select
```